# R: grImport - Ghostscript error - status 1

Tags: r, macos, ghostscript

I'm trying to use grImport insert an eps format logo into maps I'm making using R. I'm running on OsX Mavericks, R 2.15 and GhostImport 9.07.

My code looks like this:

```
    Library(grImport)
    PostScriptTrace("~/Documents/My Projects/Project A/Images/Logo Large.eps")
```

Gives me this error:

```
    GPL Ghostscript 9.07: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
    Error in PostScriptTrace("~/Documents/My Projects/Project A/Images/Logo Large.eps") : 
    status 1 in running command 'gs -q -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pswrite 
    -sOutputFile=/dev/null -sstdout=Logo Large.eps.xml captureLogo Large.eps'
```

Can anyone shed any light on this ? I have no clue whats going on here
Thanks

Edit: Ok I have got it working using advice from flodel below - bu it is only importing my eps file in black and white and missing some internal details. Anyone know what the problem is now?

Comment: Maybe running that `gs -q ...` command in a terminal will give a more meaningful error message?

Comment: You could try to copy that file into your working dir (`getwd()`) and rename it to something that does not have spaces, e.g. `Logo_Large.eps`.

Comment: Hey! THanks that putting it in the working dir and removing spaces from the filename worked. I don't know how to green a comment!

Answer (score 0):

By the look of your file name (`Logo Large.eps`) I assume you're a bioinformatician trying to get a "web logo" vector image into R. Most likely this vector image contains a lot of text which by chance could contain a font which is not in your fonts directory.

To get around this problem the easiest way you have to  convert the text in your post script file to outlines using ghost script. Just run the following line on the command line (NOT in R):

```
gs -sDEVICE=ps2write -dNOCACHE -sOutputFile=nochar_Logo_Large.eps -q -dbatch -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET Logo_Large.eps -c quit
```

After that you can use this new file in R:

```
PostScriptTrace("nochar_Logo_Large.eps", "nochar_Logo_Large.xml")
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I eventually found some other way of sticking in the logo but still good to know about this

Comment: You suggestion ? Honestly I am not working with that project at the moment - my question above is over a year old!!I think I deleted some of the code that I coulnd't get to work. But if I can squeeze it in I will have another look at it - it takes a bit of refreshing my memory

Comment: Sorry @Mehdi Nellen - I no longer have the system setup I did when I was playing with this - I did try on another system but could not get it ti work. I just don't have the time to retrace all my steps and rebuild that system